# how to use where clause on laravel eloquents that depend on relation table?

Tags: laravel

i have two tables,
one is - question table - and other is - answers table - , answer will have question_id.

I'd like to know how can i filter all questions where not has an answer yet in laravel

so i'm assuming something like

```
Forum::where(forum->comments->count(), 0)
```

i already set the relation, of course the code didn't work, just for an example

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Question::doesntHave('answers')->get();
```

if you want the count

```
Question::doesntHave('answers')->count();
```

Comment: thanks, i'll try, i don't know laravel has doesnHave method,

Comment: it so simple! works like charm, why i didn't find this in doc , thanks!

Comment: it has. Try it. It is not in the docs. You can check the laravel api